# Model of aircraft banked turn

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft-performance

I'm trying to write a model of aircraft motion during a banked turn, so for say a 60Degree roll angle constant altitude turn will require 2g lift.  However to achieve this lift the aircraft has to pull incidence.  However would this produce a nose up inclination in addition to the 60Deg roll angle ?

Comment: [Related](https://www.boldmethod.com/learn-to-fly/aerodynamics/the-aerodynamics-of-a-turn-in-an-airplane/). Note in English 'incidence' [is not what you think](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_incidence_(aerodynamics)), the proper word is angle of attack or pitch angle. In [other languages](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_(a%C3%A9rodynamique)) that would be correct.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I'm not sure what you're asking, but if you want to know about how turns and angle of attack are related then [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/30187/62) or [this one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/59615/62)

Comment: @mins it's important to clarify that angle of attack and pitch angle are different angles (as I'm absolutely certain you're well aware). Your explanation could be read to mean those are the same, and that might set someone new to flight physics on the wrong track. Hope it's OK to note.

Comment: @CptReynolds, it's a good point, my wording was not very clear. I made a graphic earlier to compare [basic angles involved in lift](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/47809/3201).